# Architecture choice for persisting hierarchical data that is perfectly well-formed

Tags: json, xml, mongodb, hierarchical-data, database

I have hierarchical data that I must persist in a database. Previously I was persisting it as xml files on the file system. The original xml had a loose structure or t, s, r, w, and l elements that allowed limited recursion (the r tag could be inside/under another r tag) and the l tag could be anywhere in the document tree. Example:

```
<root>
 <s>
  #text
 </s>
 <l/>
 <s>
  <r>
   <w/><w/><w/>
  </r>
  <l/>
  <r>
   <r>
    <w/><w/><w/>
   </r>
  </r>
  #text
 </s>
</root>
```

I was able to search for all r in such a structure with xpath relative path operator //r. 
This use-case as well as the necessity of isolating nodes //r/r and //r/w are all very important must be designed for in any implementation.

Once I looked at mongodb and how easy it is to marshall back and forth to json, I thought of storing this as a mongodb document:

```
{
 root: {
  s: [
   #text
   ,
   {
    r: [
     {
      w: [
      ]
     },
     {
      r: {
       w: [
       ]
      }
     }
    ],
    #text
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

However, searching the json data in a mongodb document proves to be a problem, since the find() syntax does not allow for any relative path searching (as was so readily available in xpath)

With all the mixed text-document xml documents out there, the problem must be one that others have already faced. How to search in a database many large mixed-hierarchical / graph-like documents. Are there any success stories? What is the best way to proceed?
These files can be 5 Meg, and I have 50 of them, so hauling them all into memory might not be a good idea. Therefore, I would like to be able to search in the data-storage.

If I stick with mongodb, which seems a good choice on the surface, I will have to:

```
0) use another searching technique besides find(), but what?
1) write my own find() function in mongodb, it's just javascript, right?
2) modify the data include more metadata of the hierarchy (parent node, path to node), ughhh 
3) modify the data in some other way, ughh
```

Maybe mongo is not the way to go. If I abandon mondodb, I must certainly:

```
4) find another database that allows an xml datatype (like sql-server)
5) find another database that allows storing tree-like structures, (like what?)
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: So, your answer seems to be, "not possible in mongodb", which I was afraid of. I'm still new to mongodb and was hopeful, but since posting this, I have been looking at basex (xml database supporting xpath queries).